# How to use sqlite3_changes() in $cordovaSQLite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I use the [sqlite3_changes()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) function in [$cordovaSQLite](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) to get the affected rows for a UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT query?

I tried to call sqlite3_changes() after I execute a query but sqlite can't find the function sqlite3_changes()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it out.

There is a `rows.affectedRows` property inside the returned promise of a SQLite query.

From the [docs](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage):

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
  console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
  console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
...
```

With this you can check how many rows are affected by a update, insert or delete query.